# Is the text overflow in the favourite questions' section unique to my setup?

Tags: support, design, fonts

It's not an issue, per se, but I noticed in the section of my profile that displays my favourite questions, the text of the number of votes overflows a small amount into the number of answers. I don't mind, but I'm curious if this is unique to my system; I use a standard Firefox install on Linux with a standard resolution font sizes. As I said, not a problem, but just a small nuance I noticed.

[image: text overflow in the favourites' section]

EDIT: This actually shows up in other places on SE too, so maybe it is my set up.

[image: more text overflow]

Comment: Did you change your browser's default font size to something larger than 16px?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Our font stack has Liberation Sans as the default font for Linux systems. That font is included by default in most major distros (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts), this includes Fedora, Ubuntu, and OpenSUSE). In Firefox on my Fedora box, your favorite question looks like this:

[image: screen shot of the same favorite question as in the OP, but with a narrower font]

As a fallback, the font stack also includes the DejaVu family (which is what your screen shot looks like), but the DejaVu fonts have the disadvantage of being extremely wide, causing the issue you see.

My advice is to install the Liberation font family on your machine; even if your distro doesn't include it by default, it's very likely available in the repositories.

Comment: Yes,that was it. I use Arch Linux, and it wasn't installed or enabled by default. Thank you!